# Change Mario Yoshi pose

Tags: building, set-modification, super-mario

I'm returning to Lego as an adult and struggling with what I thought would be a small project.

Please tell me if this is off topic but as it has a hard answer of no or this is how I though it would be ok.

What I'm trying to do is change the pose of the Lego Mario Yoshi but the way it is built I cant see any way of moving anything.

The goal is from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I would go about this or is the original design too limiting to make it a possibility?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally got around to making an attempt at designing a pose for Yoshi.

I received set [71406](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=71406-1) Yoshi's Gift House as part of [2023 Q2 Activity Support](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/606/13390), from which I could have a copy of the original Yoshi as a basis for the task.

I tried to remain faithful to the style of the original Lego version, while still capturing the 'reaching forward' and 'open-mouthed' look of the new pose.

I also kept in mind to limit the additional parts required, and try to use commonly available parts if required.

See my result for yourself:

[image: yoshi with tongue out]

It's a fairly simple assembly, this photo should be easy to follow:

[image: yoshi assembly]

Only ~10 additional parts are required. (I didn't own ALL the desired colours and parts)
These are the ideal parts you'll need to recreate it: *(replace Lime with whatever colour your Yoshi is)*

| Qty | Colour | Part |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Lime | [Bracket 1 x 2 - 1 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99781&C=34) (shown here in Light Bluish Grey) |
| 1 | Lime | [Slope 30 1 x 2 x 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85984&C=34) or 2 of [Slope 30 1 x 1 x 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54200&C=34) (shown) |
| 1 | White | [Slope 30 1 x 2 x 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85984&C=1) or 2 of [Slope 30 1 x 1 x 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54200&C=1) (shown) |
| 2 | Lime | [Plate 2 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3021&C=34) |
| 1 | Red | [Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85861&C=5) |
| 1 | Red | [Bar 6.6L with Stop Ring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4095&C=5) (shown) or [Bar 6L with Stop Ring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=63965&C=5) |
| 1 | Black | [Brick 1 x 1 with Studs on 4 Sides](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4733&C=11) or perhaps another colour |
| 1 | White | [Slope 30 1 x 1 x 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54200&C=1) |

[image: additional parts]